# Why was my off-topic flag declined on a question that has since been removed

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, flag-history

I flagged this question as off-topic because it was not a programming related question, therefore containing no code and lacked detail. My flag was declined and I do not understand why. I am new to SO so an explanation would be very beneficial. The question has since been removed or closed, as the link redirects to "Page Not Found",  which would appear to me that it was maybe flagged again by someone else and a moderator intervened?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559638/why-is-itunes-connect-paying-me-less-than-what-i-earned

See my screenshots below:

[image: My Flagging History showing that 1 was declined]

[image: Screenshot with details of declined flag]

**EDIT:** At the time of flagging the question I did not get the options/screens that user @Shog9 has added in answer below. I only received these options as far as I remember:
[image: Options for Flagging]

Comment: It looks like you used a custom moderator flag and just typed "This question is off-topic." You should use standard flags for that, or moderators are likely to reject your flag. Might be that the mod was rejecting for that and just hit the wrong message.

Comment: @Kendra That exactly the right rejection message when someone uses an inappropriate flag like this.  You're not supposed to use a custom mod flag when you think a question is off topic, which is what that message says.

Comment: @Servy I thought there was one about using the standard flags. Maybe I was imagining that.

Comment: @Kendra Was probably something the mod typed out manually rather than a canned response.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:** It appears as though you opened the dialog *as the post was being deleted*. This would've resulted in two unfortunate consequences:

1. You wouldn't get a close option.
2. The moderator responding to your custom flag would've found the question already deleted at the time you raised it.

...thus leaving you confused, and the moderator with nothing to be done.

We could probably stand to add a note to the flag dialog in these cases explaining why options are missing.

---

There's an actual "this should be closed as off-topic" flag:

[image: blatantly off-topic]

...and then there's typing "This question is off-topic." in the "in need of moderator intervention" textbox:

[image]

Do the former, not the latter. Also, the question is gone now because the author deleted it themselves, probably because someone helpfully *told them* it was off-topic in the comments.

Comment: Note that "off-topic" does not actually appear in the "should be closed..." option or its description. It only appears in its submenu. The keyword is really "closed" - the action that's taken on a question when it is deemed off-topic.

Comment: Huh... That seems like an oversight.

Comment: Thanks for your clear advise @Shog9. I have updated my question with an additional screenshot if you could please advise why I only received those 3 options and not the ones you have provided.

Comment: I edited my answer to address that, @fionaredmond

Comment: I see that now - thanks. Is the fact now that my flagged history is showing 1 declined flag affecting my reputation in any way? When I go to flag a new question now I receive the following message: **"Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!"**

Comment: No; you'll get a warning when you go to flag again, but that's it. Don't be overly concerned about it, @fionaredmond

Answer (score 2):

You should not use a custom moderator flag to ask for a question to be closed.  If you think a question should be closed, choose the flag reason that specifically states you think the question should be closed.

Note that the question was deleted by its owner (which the deletion page specifically tells you) and not by a moderator or the community (although it was half way to being closed by the community).

Comment: I did not get the option to ask for the question to be closed. I only received the options in my last screenshot: 1) spam, 2) rude or abusive or 3) in need of moderator intervention.

Comment: @fionaredmond Then you weren't flagging the question, or the question, or the question had already been deleted.